# Rotate X Axis labels in Highchart Gantt

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using Highcharts Gantt to display my data. But I've stacked with one problem: I cannot rotate X-Axis labels. Sometime I have to display long time period on the small screen and it looks like on this pic:[image: Months]

It's almost 4 year on this pic and some moths are missed. The best solution (in my opinion) is to rotate labels. I've tried this:
 `xAxis: { labels: { rotation: 90 } }`, but it seems that this not working for Gantt. The full working example is here: (code copied from Highchart documentation)

```js
Highcharts.ganttChart('container', {

    title: {
        text: 'Left Axis as Table'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickPixelInterval: 70,
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                week: "%w"
            },
            labels: {
                rotation: 90
            }
    },

    yAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        grid: {
            enabled: true,
            borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            columns: [{
                title: {
                    text: 'Project'
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{point.name}'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Assignee'
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{point.assignee}'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'Est. days'
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        var point = this.point,
                            days = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
                            number = (point.x2 - point.x) / days;
                        return Math.round(number * 100) / 100;
                    }
                }
            }, {
                labels: {
                    format: '{point.start:%e. %b}'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Start date'
                }
            }, {
                title: {
                    text: 'End date'
                },
                offset: 30,
                labels: {
                    format: '{point.end:%e. %b}'
                }
            }]
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        xDateFormat: '%e %b %Y, %H:%M'
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Project 1',
        data: [{
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 18, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Start prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 0
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 20, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 24, 16),
            name: 'Develop',
            assignee: 'Michaels',
            y: 1
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 25, 16),
            name: 'Prototype done',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 2
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 27, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 3, 16),
            name: 'Test prototype',
            assignee: 'Richards',
            y: 3
        }, {
            start: Date.UTC(2017, 10, 23, 8),
            end: Date.UTC(2017, 11, 15, 16),
            name: 'Run acceptance tests',
            assignee: 'Halliburton',
            y: 4
        }]
    }],

    exporting: {
        sourceWidth: 1000
    }
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    min-width: 800px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
.scrolling-container {
    overflow-x: auto;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/highcharts-gantt.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/gantt/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div class="scrolling-container">
    <div id="container"></div>
</div>
```

Is some other way to rotate X-Axis labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that the rotation feature is not supported if `grid` is enabled for an axis. You can disable `grid` (example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Ltnhu739/) or write a piece of code to operate directly on svg elements:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            render: function() {
                const ticks = this.xAxis[0].ticks;

                for (let tickPos in ticks) {
                    ticks[tickPos].label.attr({
                        rotate: -90,
                        translateX: 10
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y9kqf1xu/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr